# How to use own python modules without rewriting all paths in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I am making a website with django that uses my python codes. my directory is like this:

```
\mysite
    \myApp
    \myCodes
        \common
        \deploy
        \src
           misc.py
              def Args():
                  # commands


    \mySite
```

my codes in `/myCodes/src` have a lines at the beginning like:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('../deploy')
sys.path.append('../common')
```

some codes in `/common` and `/deploy` also have the same lines and they work fine but when I use my codes in from the `view.py` they can't find each other, I added `\myCodes` as an app in `settings.py` and when I manually change the import dir (`import myCodes.common.myFunction`) it is fine but it seams to be unnecessary to manually change all of the imports, is there away I can execute the codes as they are?

P.s: I also use directory as input and open and write files in my functions that don't work (the are all in `\myCodes` directory)

Comment: How about adding `sys.path.append('../..')` to scripts in `src`, then using `myCodes.common` everywhere? I don't recommend trying to use `common.myFunction` in your views, because then the same code will be available as `common.myFunction` and `myCodes.common.myFunction`, which is fragile.

Comment: @Alasdair when I use `myCodes.common` the files are found but the problem is that I have to change a lot of lines since there are a lot of directories in my codes

Comment: You can add `sys.path('myCodes/common')` to your `wsgi.py`, but as I said I don't recommend that. If you aren't going to use `mycodes.common` when you import those modules, then it might be clearer to move `mycodes` to sit next to the `mysite` directory.

Comment: @Alasdair Okay so I moved `myCodes` next to `mysite` directory and `import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) +'../../myCodes/src')

from misc import Args` but got ` ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'misc'`

Comment: There's not enough information to help you debug. I don't know which file you added `sys.path.append`, and I don't know what file `misc` refers to.

Comment: @Alasdair I added the directory of `src` folder which contains `misc.py`

Comment: You still haven't said which file you added `sys.path.append()` to. I would avoid using `..` or `__file__` to begin with. Use `sys.path.append('/full/path/to/myCodes/src')`. Once that's working, you can try to use a relative path.

Comment: @Alasdair thank you I used `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to give full path and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `os.path.dirname(__file__)`+'/rest of the dir/' to give full path and it worked